# Firefox in Ubuntu

Tags: startup, iphone, photo

Since I installed Ubuntu on my laptop, Firefox seems to behave differently.

1. I cannot go back to previous pages with backspace any longer.
2. I cannot bookmark all open tabs in one folder anymore.
3. If I want to drop downloaded files on my desktop from the download tab (downfacing arrow in the top-right corner of my browser), it only copies a .txt file to my desktop.

Anyone with explanation/solution here?

Thanks!!

Comment: All you mentioned never worked in Linux.

Comment: re: #2 If you right-click a tab you get a choice to "Bookmark all tabs"

Comment: `control+[` goes back, `control+]` goes forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Does not work in ubuntu. However, you can install [VimFx](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimfx/) firefox addon and use `ctrl + h` to go back and `ctrl + l` to go forward. However this feels a little weired at first, but after a while you wont be able to live without it.
2. `ctrl + shift + d` won't work. You need to right click on a tab, and select `Bookmark all tabs..`
3. I don't have an answer for this one.